# Connect 4: Check for winner

Tags: delphi, pascal

In Delphi, I have a Connect 4 board representation (7 columns x 6 lines) in form of an array:

```
TBoard = Array[1..7, 1..6] of SmallInt;
Board: TBoard; // instance ob TBoard
```

Each element can have three different states:

- 1 = player 1's pieces
- 0 = empty
- -1 = player 2's pieces

Now I need a function which checks if there's a winner or a draw:

```
function CheckForWinner(): SmallInt;
```

... where 1 is player 1's win, 0 is a draw, -1 is player 2's win and "nil" is for a game which has not ended yet.

My draft is as follows - split into two single functions:

```
function CheckForWinner(): SmallInt;
var playerToCheck: ShortInt;
    s, z: Byte;
    draw: Boolean;
begin
  draw := TRUE;
  for s := 1 to 7 do begin
    for z := 1 to 6 do begin
      if Board[s, z] = 0 then draw := FALSE; // if there are empty fields then it is no draw
    end;
  end;
  if draw then begin
    result := 0;
  end
  else begin
    playerToCheck := Board[lastPieceX, lastPieceY]; // only for last-moving player
    if searchRow(playerToCheck, +1, 0, lastPieceX, lastPieceY) then // search right/left
      result := playerToCheck
    else if searchRow(playerToCheck, 0, +1, lastPieceX, lastPieceY) then // search up/down
      result := playerToCheck
    else if searchRow(playerToCheck, +1, +1, lastPieceX, lastPieceY) then // search right-down/left-up
      result := playerToCheck
    else if searchRow(playerToCheck, +1, -1, lastPieceX, lastPieceY) then // search right-up/left-down
      result := playerToCheck;
    else
      result := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;

function searchRow(player: SmallInt; sChange, zChange: ShortInt; startS, startZ: Byte): Boolean;
var inRow, s, z: SmallInt;
begin
  inRow := 0;
  s := startS;
  z := startZ;
  while (Board[s, z] = player) AND (inRow < 4) AND (s >= 1) AND (s <= 7) AND (z >= 1) AND (z <= 6) do begin
    s := s+sChange;
    z := z+zChange;
    inRow := inRow+1;
  end;
  s := startS-sChange;
  z := startZ-zChange;
  while (Board[s, z] = player) AND (inRow < 4) AND (s >= 1) AND (s <= 7) AND (z >= 1) AND (z <= 6) do begin
    s := s-sChange;
    z := z-zChange;
    inRow := inRow+1;
  end;
  if inRow = 4 then
    result := TRUE
  else
    result := FALSE;
end;
```

What do you think of this approach? Do you have a better (faster / shorter) solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect the rules to this games are very simple. You should have saved us the Google search by providing the rules in the question. I for want don't feel like googleing the rules, only to find out you're actually playing by a different set of rules.

Comment: And you only need to check from the point where the last piece is dropped.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I've already implemented this as you can see ;)

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: I was assuming everyone knows the rules as it is a very famous game, sorry. And I do play by the same set of rules as it is usual?!

Comment: @Marco Just do what Golez says and brute force it from the latest drop.

Comment: The only thing I see is the use of s and schange instead of y, just seems weird and harder to read

Comment: I think it's actually smart to pass the changes for x and y in a parameter. But you do have a little bug. It is allowed to have more than 4 in a row, which is possible when you drop a piece in the middle. Your code checks for exactly 4.

Comment: @Marco Are any of the answers below useful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for a winner in very much the same way as you do, only with a little less code.
I think you wouldn't need to check all fields to determine if the game is done. Just increase a counter when you drop a piece in the game. The game is a draw if the counter reaches 42 and there is no winner yet.

```
function CheckRow(x, y, xd, yd: Integer): Boolean;
var
  c: Integer;

  function RowLength(x, y, xd, yd: Integer): Integer;
  begin
    Result := 0;
    repeat
      Inc(Result);
      Inc(x, xd);
      Inc(y, yd);
    until not ((x in [1..7]) and (y in [1..6]) and (Board[x, y] = c));
  end;

begin
  c := Board[x, y];

  Result := 4 <= RowLength(x, y, xd, yd) + RowLength(x, y, xd*-1, yd*-1) - 1;
end;

function CheckForWinner(x, y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if CheckRow(x, y, 0, 1) or CheckRow(x, y, 1, 1) or
     CheckRow(x, y, 1, 0) or CheckRow(x, y, 1, -1) then
    Result := Board[x,y];
end;
```

Comment: This has a bug. I'll give you your up-vote back if you can find and fix it!!

Comment: It has? I did some testing, though not very extensive. I can't imagine what it is, though. You can't break it by passing invalid x, y (although it probably won't return the the right value then). And it will even work with a variable number of players as long as neither of them has player nr 0. :)

Comment: Oops you're right. Checking from topleft to bottom right is wrong. 0, -1 should be 1, -1. :o

Answer (score 4):

I didn't read your code.  I just elected to write some myself with a blank slate.

Here's my version:

```
const
  RowCount = 6;
  ColCount = 7;

type
  TState = (stNone, stA, stB);
  TBoard = array [1..RowCount] of array [1..ColCount] of TState;

function ValidLocation(Row, Col: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := InRange(Row, 1, RowCount) and InRange(Col, 1, ColCount);
end;

procedure Check(
  const Board: TBoard;
  const StartRow, StartCol: Integer;
  const RowDelta, ColDelta: Integer;
  out Winner: TState
);
var
  Row, Col, Count: Integer;
  State: TState;
begin
  Winner := stNone;
  Row := StartRow;
  Col := StartCol;
  State := Board[Row, Col];
  if State=stNone then
    exit;
  Count := 0;
  while ValidLocation(Row, Col) and (Board[Row, Col]=State) do begin
    inc(Count);
    if Count=4 then begin
      Winner := State;
      exit;
    end;
    inc(Row, RowDelta);
    inc(Col, ColDelta);
  end;
end;

function Winner(const Board: TBoard): TState;
var
  Row, Col: Integer;
begin
  for Row := 1 to RowCount do begin
    for Col := 1 to ColCount do begin
      Check(Board, Row, Col, 0, 1, Result);//check row
      if Result<>stNone then
        exit;
      Check(Board, Row, Col, 1, 0, Result);//check column
      if Result<>stNone then 
        exit;
      Check(Board, Row, Col, 1, 1, Result);//check diagonal
      if Result<>stNone then 
        exit;
      Check(Board, Row, Col, 1, -1, Result);//check other diagonal
      if Result<>stNone then 
        exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := stNone;
end;
```

Big long pile of code. Uses brute force approach, not that performance matters for Connect 4. Don't like the four identical `if Result<>stNone then exit;` lines, but you can surely think of a cleaner way. Code has not been run. It might not even work!! Just the way my brain attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: `then begin exit; end`? What's wrong with `then exit;`? Personally, I *hate* when people place `begin` on the same line as the thing before it, and also when you use `begin` and `end` where you don't need to. But Marjan has taught me not to complain about it too much! (And yes, I know the arguments supporting this style that I don't like.)

Still +1 for some nice code.

Comment: I just always do it that way, it's my Modula-2 heritage. Sorry! I seem to recall having some discussion with Deltics on this subject.

Comment: @David: now you can't put a breakpoint on that Exit statements. Nice algorithm though.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks. Nice eh, but not nice enough for an up-vote!!  ;-) Seriously don't waste it, I'm capped. Updated to make it breakpoint friendly. Not that you'd ever need to debug this code!! Ha ha.

Comment: Just updated to fix the bug! I was checking the same diagonal twice in the original code!!

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks. I guess I'll have to fit in with the style police from now on!!  ;-)

Comment: Well, that plus the fix. I like people giving real attention to what they do.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I haven't studied the algorithm in detail. The comments below are merely my first reactions after staring at the code for less than ten seconds.*

I have some very quick remarks. First, I think

```
TCellState = (csUnoccupied, csPlayerA, csPlayerB)
TBoard = Array[1..7, 1..6] of TCellState;
```

is nicer. Of course, you can save compatibility with your old code by doing

```
TCellState = (csUnoccupied = 0, csPlayerA = 1, csPlayerB = -1)
```

Second,

```
draw := true;
for s := 1 to 7 do begin
  for z := 1 to 6 do begin
    if Board[s, z] = 0 then draw := false;
  end;
end;
```

You don't need the `begin` and `end` parts:

```
draw := TRUE;
for s := 1 to 7 do
  for z := 1 to 6 do
    if Board[s, z] = 0 then
      draw := false;
```

More importantly, as a gain in performance, you should break the loops as soon as you have set `drawn` to false:

```
draw := true;
for s := 1 to 7 do
  for z := 1 to 6 do
    if Board[s, z] = 0 then
    begin
      draw := false;
      break;
    end;
```

This will, however, only break the `z` loop. To break both loops, the nicest way is to put the entire block above in a local function. Let's call it `CheckDraw`:

```
function CheckDraw: boolean;
begin
  result := true;
  for s := 1 to 7 do
    for z := 1 to 6 do
      if Board[s, z] = 0 then
        Exit(false);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use `label` and `goto` to break out of both loops at once.

**Update**

I see now that you can just do

```
for s := 1 to 7 do
  for z := 1 to 6 do
    if Board[s, z] = 0 then
      Exit(0);
```

and you don't even need to introduce the `draw` local variable!

**End update**

Furthermore,

```
if inRow = 4 then
   result := TRUE
 else
   result := FALSE;
```

is bad. You should do just

```
result := inRow = 4;
```

Finally, In my taste

```
s := s+sChange;
```

should be written

```
inc(s, sChange);
```

and

```
inRow := inRow+1
```

should be

```
inc(inRow);
```

Oh, and `nil` is a pointer, not an integer.

Comment: +1 That said, I think performance is irrelevant here. The issue is correctness. Having made that point, I hope to goodness my answer is actually correct!!!

Comment: @David: No, performance isn't an issue. But what if the upper-left cell is unoccupied? It doesn't feel good to continue iterating when you have found the answer. Especially if you can skip the unnecessary iterations while making the code shorter at the same time! Optimization for free!

Answer (score 1):

The source code from the Fhourstones Benchmark from John Tromp uses a fascinating algorithm for testing a connect four game for a win. The algorithm uses following bitboard representation of the game:

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  TOP
5 12 19 26 33 40 47
4 11 18 25 32 39 46
3 10 17 24 31 38 45
2  9 16 23 30 37 44
1  8 15 22 29 36 43
0  7 14 21 28 35 42  BOTTOM
```

There is one bitboard for the red player and one for the yellow player. 0 represents a empty cell, 1 represents a filled cell. The bitboard is stored in an unsigned 64 bit integer variable. The bits 6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 41, >= 48 have to be 0.

The algorithm is:

```
// return whether 'board' includes a win
bool haswon(unsigned __int64 board)
{
    unsigned __int64 y = board & (board >> 6);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 6))     // check \ diagonal
        return true;
    y = board & (board >> 7);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 7))     // check horizontal
        return true;
    y = board & (board >> 8);
    if (y & (y >> 2 * 8))     // check / diagonal
        return true;
    y = board & (board >> 1);
    if (y & (y >> 2))         // check vertical
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

You have to call the function for the bitboard of the player who did the last move